# Conflict between Spritekit and UIKit co-ordinates

Tags: ios7, coordinates, sprite-kit

I have a question that I think should have a simple answer (which I haven't found yet!). In my SKScene, all the nodes are positioned and move along a path properly (based on origin at lower left) but when I collect the users touch co-ordinates in this view (code below), these are returned based on a UIKit origin (upper left). I'm sure I'm missing something really simple here; any help would be appreciated!

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  

        UITouch *move=[[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint movepoint=[move locationInView:self.view];
        [_guide runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self] duration:0.01 ]];

        if (recording){
            if (_MovePointsArray==NULL) {
                _MovePointsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            }
            [_MovePointsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:movepoint]];
        }
        curx=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", movepoint.x];
        myXPos.text=curx;
        cury=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", movepoint.y];
        myYPos.text=cury;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute

```
CGPoint movepoint = [move locationInView:self.view];
```

With

```
CGPoint movepoint = [move locationInNode:self];
```

Signatures of each

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
- (CGPoint)locationInNode:(SKNode *)node
```